# Expand UITableViewCell to occupy all remaining screen space

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've got a UITableView (filling whole screen) with several dynamic sections (these could be added/removed at any time). These sections are pulling data from various sources and if there are no data the section wouldn't show. There is one section in the middle which is always there and if there are no data for that one either it should show single row filling the whole screen (minus the header) showing label like "no data found".

So say I've got sections A, B, C, D, E. Section D is always visible but the rest might or might not be there. I'm resizing the D cell based on table's contentSize but the problem happens when there is something in section E. In that case when drawing the section D the contentSize seems to be wrong - I guess it's because at that time section E hasn't been drawn yet. It works fine when there is no section E visible.

Is there any way how I can have cell in the middle of the table dynamically resize based on how much space the table content is taking on the actual screen?

Or maybe my solution is completely wrong and there is a better way?

**EDIT**
I've added a picture - please excuse my terrible drawing. Basically if there is not enough data in other sections - the single cell in section D (green rectangle) should expand to take remainder of the screen in case the table content is not taking up the whole screen.

[[image]

Comment: Please show some code or at least a diagram of what you're trying to achieve. Hard to visualize and troubleshoot what you're trying to do.

Comment: First of all...You want section to take up the screen height or table view cell? Since section actually means something specific in context of UITableView. Also if you want cell to occupy entire screen, then just return device screen height from UITableView delegate cell height method.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand - section is made of header, footer and cells so can't really see how section can take up cell. I want that cell to take up any remaining free space on the screen since the table data aren't filling the whole screen.